# Gherkin to (not for) Javascript

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I am new to BDD and Gherkin. Trying to use Cucumber, which parses Gherkin to Ruby - a language I don't know. Is there any library which converts Gherkin to Javascript ? If I get the Javascript output for Gherkin, I plan to modify the code and call some Javascript functions of my own. Please note, I am not planning to test these javascript functions - these functions are from some other testing tool I am trying to chain to.
I Hope I am not planning to do something weird. All the problem is that our team does not want to learn Ruby. Please suggest some options.

I guess, what I need is a tool which allows me to write step definitions in javascript - as opposed to Ruby.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for Cucumber.js: http://git.io/cukejs

Answer (score 0):

[Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin/) is a human-readable DSL, and cucumber doesn't care what language you use to create the step definitions.

While I don't see any javascript-specific [examples](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/examples) on the cucumber wiki, you might want to check out [cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js).

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber.js is a good option and Kyuri is a good alternative if you the stuff from nodejitsu :) https://github.com/nodejitsu/kyuri

Answer (score 0):

You can try a cucumber.js authoring tool, called [CukeTest](http://cuketest.com), it has the following relevant feature.

- Generate JavaScript code from steps text
- Prompt you whether there are existing/pending/duplicate definition for a step.
- Given a particular step definition code in JavaScript file, jump to the step definition that matches it
- Switch from visual editing view to text view

There are both desktop version available, or [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/cuketest/9p9lchrp8kb8) version. Here is a demo:

[image]